# SQL half join from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have doubt on  below on query of below tables

## Invoices no| Agreement No

```
  1     |     0       |
  2     |     0       |
  3     |     101     |
  4     |     102     |
  5     |     201     |
  1     |     201     |
```

daily agreement table -

## Agreement no|Agreement Status

```
  101   |     closed      |
  102   |     open        |
```

monthly agreement table -

## Agreement no|Agreement Status

```
  201   |     closed      |
  202   |     open        |
```

i want to create a query to select invoices with agreement no and agreement status

please help

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with left joins. Replace these table and column aliases with yours and this will be the code:

```
SELECT
      InvoiceNo
    , A.AgreementNo
    , [AgreementStatus] = IFNull(B.AgreementStatus, C.AgreementStatus)
FROM
    Agreements AS A
        LEFT JOIN
    DailyAgreements AS B
        ON A.AgreementNo = B.AgreementNo
        LEFT JOIN
    MonthlyAgreements AS C
        ON A.AgreementNo = C.AgreementNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join the status tables and use `CASE` to check whether the monthly or daily status table was joined:

```
SELECT 
    i.invoice_no
    , i.agreement_no
    , CASE WHEN da.agreement_status IS NULL THEN ma.agreement_status ELSE da.agreement_status END as agreement_status
FROM invoice as i
LEFT JOIN daily_agreement as da ON da.agreement_no = i.agreement_no
LEFT JOIN monthly_agreement as ma ON ma.agreement_no = i.agreement_no
```

**EDIT:**

My query should return rows like this:

```
invoice_no  | agreement_no| agreement_status
      1     |     0       | null
      2     |     0       | null
      3     |     101     | closed
      4     |     102     | open
      5     |     201     | closed
      1     |     201     | closed
```